# Call to node js server from JS project

Tags: java, node.js

I've simple JS program and inside I've folder with node js application .
I wanted somehow to call to the nodejs application (similar to node server.js)
there is a way to do that from java project.
example will be very helpful

UPDATE

This for example my node file .I've just the following file which is called server.js

```
var express = require('express');


var app = express();


app.get('/', function (req, res) {

res.send("Hello world");
});


var server = app.listen(3012, function () {
        console.log("server is listening to port" + 3012)
    }
)
```

Comment: What do you want to call from Java project? How do you want to call it, from servlet or from the front-end of Java project? Do you want a simple HTTP request? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Салман - I dont care how to call it :) from servlet you name it,I need to create some poc to invoke node js application from java code in any way,is it possible ,Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to run node server.js from java project than you can do that by running terminal commands from java in directory where your server.js files is present

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            {"node server.js"});
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot voted up! Since Im fairly new to JAVA(im familiar with client side like node...). what is the steps which I should do to make it run.(I've download eclipse and intelij ...) thanks in advance! I just want to run hello world node application from java

Comment: Sure I'll do that :),can you please provide the steps to run it since I new to java, which java project to create and where to put the provided code...I want to make it work...

Comment: @shopiaT can you make simple program which just print "hello world"

Comment: Please see my update post,Lets say that I've just this node file and I want to put it on java application and call to server.js what should I do?thanks!

Comment: @shopiaT There are two ways to do that either start node server from java project as did in above program or use hit the running nodejs server from java program

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83124/discussion-between-shopia-t-and-user111111111).